# Broadcast Receiver - is using one better than many?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Here's my current setting in my android manifest:

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BaseReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".receivers.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I've separeted those receivers because the packages only work with `<data android:scheme="package" />` and the boot receiver stops working if I add thise schema to my filter.

**Now my question:**

Does that consume more battery? Or does it matter if I summarize the package receivers in one? Or can I just create as many receivers as I want as android will not run anything and just checks the manifests of all installed apps on demand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Receivers are handled by the system. That is the system that send a message when the action happened so you can as many receivers as you want it won't affect the battery you just have to handle them properly.

And for the question one or many, it depend of the use you make of them. It will be easier to handle one in certain cases, for other cases it will be easier to have many to handle them separetly.

Comment: thanks. that answers my question and confirms what I thought